# Android Firebase cant add child and setvalue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I did it like in the documentation, but the values ​​I send are not registered in the database either.
I can add to the database before I login, but I can not add after login
My code is that way

```
    edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_namepro);
    edit_adress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_adresspro);
    String name = edit_name.getText().toString().trim();
    String adress = edit_adress.getText().toString().trim();
    User userInfo = new User(name,adress);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        db.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInfo.name);
        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    edit_adress.setText("");
    edit_name.setText("");
```

My rules are that

```
 {
"rules": {
".read": "auth ==null",
".write": "auth == null"
}
 }
```

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: A quick guess is that your user isn't signed in yet when you write to the database. To detect that, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201703102014506234863

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I tried to write to the database in MainActivity and it happened. But I can not register in the database after I login.

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules state that read/write operations are only allowed when the user is **not** signed in. Is this intentional?

Sorry, try changing both rules to:

```
auth != null
```

Comment: Thank you for answer .No , how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

and make sure user gets logged in before putting anything on firebase. This helps to keep track of data inputted on firebase.